# Работа со списками в Java

Tags: java, list, for, int

При вызове метода `.size()` у `ArrayList` мы даём команду пересчитать размер списка или просто считываем из памяти "служебную" переменную, которая хранит размер списка?

Предположим, имеется список из 1_000_000 очень больших строк. *Будет ли разница в скорости работы между двумя реализациями?*

Первый вариант:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {...}
```

Второй вариант:

```
int k = list.size();
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {...}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас 2 разных вопроса.

1. да в ArrayList есть переменная с размером. В конце-концов массив всегда знает свой размер. И именно его просто возвращает `list.size()`
2. будет ли на каждой итерации заново получаться значение размера, т.е. будет ли каждый раз вызываться функция `list.size()`?
   Если в теле цикла не изменять размер массива, то ваши варианты одинаковы. В том смысле, что оптимизатор вероятнее всего закеширует значение, возвращаемое `list.size()` и не будет даже вызывать функцию на каждой итерации. И первый вариант будет одинаковым со вторым.
   А если в теле цикла изменить массив, то работа первого варианта будет отличаться от второго. И проблемы можно получить при обоих вариантах.

Comment: Как наверняка избежать проблем в ситуации, когда оптимизатор закеширует значение, а размер списка изменился в процессе работы цикла?

Comment: @IvanNaStackOF Самое правильное - не итерироваться по списку используя размер в случаях когда надо изменять размер массива. Для этого есть итераторы. Итерироваться нужно до последнего элемента `for( i=list.begin() ; i!=list.end() ; i++ )` И проблема не в размере, хотя в случае уменьшения размера вы можете выйти за пределы массива. Проблема в другом - вы пропустите какие-то значения. Если размер увеличился - вы не дойдете до конца. Или если элементы будут вставлены в позицию до итератора - получится что этот элемент вы пропустили, а текущий обработаете дважды.

Comment: @IvanNaStackOF А вообще оптимизаторы умные - если в теле цикла изменяется контейнер, то `list.size()` кэшироваться не будет. Но это всё равно не убережет от ошибок.

Answer (score 3):

У класса [`ArrayList`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java) есть свойство `private int size`, которое содержит длину списка. Метод

```
public int size() {
        return size;
    }
```

возвращает значение этого свойства. Т.е. ответ такой - при запросе длины списка он не пересчитывается (по сути - "просто считываем из памяти "служебную" переменную", как вы написали).